# using data.table to replace multiple columns on single condition

Tags: r, data.table

I want to change the default value (which is 255) to NA.

```
dt <- data.table(x = c(1,5,255,0,NA), y = c(1,7,255,0,0), z = c(4,2,7,8,255))
coords <- c('x', 'y')
```

Which gives the following code:

```
     x   y   z
1:   1   1   4
2:   5   7   2
3: 255 255   7
4:   0   0   8
5:  NA   0 255
```

I the furthest I came up with is this:

```
dt[.SD == 255, (.SD) := NA, .SDcols = coords]
```

Please note that column z stays the same. So just the columns which are specified and not all columns.

But that doesn't help me to get the sollution:

```
     x   y   z
1:   1   1   4
2:   5   7   2
3:  NA  NA   7
4:   0   0   8
5:  NA   0 255
```

I am looking for a sustainable solution because the original dataset is a couple of million rows.

EDIT:

I have found a solution but it is quite ugly and is definately too slow as it takes almost 10 seconds to get through a dataframe of 22009 x 86. Does anyone have a better solution?

The code:

`dt[, replace(.SD, .SD == 255, NA), .SDcols = coords, by = c(colnames(dt)[!colnames(dt) %in% coords])]`

Comment: You can try `dt[, replace(.SD, .SD == 255, NA)]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sotos. I edited my post. I am looking for a solution that is easily upscalable when the amount of rows heavily increase. I am not sure if the function replace is that friendly.

Comment: couple of million rows is not very big. `replace` will do just fine

Comment: okay, thank you. But it doesn't include the other columns.

Comment: You can do this when you read in the table:  `fread("path/to/file", na.strings=c("NA", "255"))`

Comment: `.SD` includes all columns. What do you mean?

Comment: `dt[, replace(.SD, .SD == 255, NA), .SDcols = coords]` shows only the edited columns. It might be the case that one of the other columns in the data.table also has the value '255' in it's columns. I don't want those columns change, only the ones specified.

Comment: Scott, that might be possible when I read it. Sadly I am using a locked package with SQL-statements. Specifying every row within that statement and 'just' making every value NA isn't what I want.

Comment: There is `.SDcols`in data table where you can specify the columns you want to change

Comment: @Sotos, I edited my OP. I did find a solution myself but in my opinion it is really ugly. It is using the by-statement to pass the rest of the columns. It is also really slow, as it takes almost 10 seconds to get through a data.table of size: 22009 x 86

Comment: @Tunder250 see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you can keep the columns outside `.SDcols`,

```
library(data.table)
dt[, (coords) := replace(.SD, .SD == 255, NA), .SDcols = coords]
```

which gives,

> ```
>     x  y   z
> 1:  1  1   4
> 2:  5  7   2
> 3: NA NA   7
> 4:  0  0   8
> 5: NA  0 255
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```r
require(data.table)
dt[ ,
    (coords) := lapply(.SD, function(x) fifelse(x == 255, NA_real_, x)),
    .SDcols = coords ]
```

Having compared it to Sotos' answer, it also seems a little bit faster.

Comment: I find this approach much more intuitive especially when swapping out the fifelse for any other function you might want to create or use